# Анимация перемещения при realyout

Tags: javascript, css

Есть несколько элементов в строке. При скрытии (`display:none`) одного из них - остальные смещаются влево. Каким образом можно анимировать перемещающиеся элементы (сделать плавное перемещение)?

Comment: напишите `visibility:hidden` вместо `display:none` вроде бы должно это помочь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

свойство `display` не анимируется. Можно плавно уменьшать размеры. Нижеследующий пример работает при наведении.

```css
.slideToggle{
  display:inline-block;
  font-style:italic;
  color:red;
  max-width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition:all .5s ease;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  white-space:nowrap;  
}
p:hover .slideToggle{
  max-width:0;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="slideToggle">toggle me, toggle me completly</span> asdasd asd asd asdasd asd asd asd asd</p>
```